# Does RubyMotion work well with facebook-ios-sdk?

Tags: ios, facebook, rubymotion

Before purchase RubyMotion, I'd like to know does it support 3rd party SDKs, e.g.: `facebook-ios-sdk`?

Comment: RubyMotion [uses CocoaPods for dependencies](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/cocoapods/). The Facebook-iOS-SDK is listed in the [specs for CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) so I would assume that it would work fine. I am using third party libraries like `AFNetworking` using this method with no problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't tested thoroughly, and can't speak for all SDKs/libraries, I can confirm that this specific SDK compiles and works in a RubyMotion project. You just need to follow the CocoaPods instructions on the RubyMotion site, and add the following to your `Rakefile`:

```
require 'motion-cocoapods'

# In the setup block, add this:
app.pods do
  dependency 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
end
```

Then when you run `rake`, support will be compiled in.